# MySQL Left outer join query too slow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

I have 3 tables:

orders (5429850 rows), order_lines (PK id, FK order_id, 18530647 rows), order_line_allocations (PK id, FK order_line_id, 112594 rows)

`order_lines` and `order_line_allocations` stores the accounts related info. For single account case we store account data in order_lines table and for multiple accounts use-case we store data in allocations table.

I am trying to write a query to fetch orders satisfying user account restrictions.

```
SELECT `orders`.`id` FROM `orders` 
LEFT JOIN `order_lines` ON `order_lines`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN order_line_allocations ON order_line_allocations.order_line_id = order_lines.id
LEFT JOIN (select sec_accounts.id from accounts sec_accounts
  WHERE (sec_accounts.account_type_id = 344 AND ((`sec_accounts`.`segment_1` = 'MS')))
) as non_alloc_accounts ON non_alloc_accounts.id = order_lines.account_id AND order_lines.allocation_count = 0
LEFT JOIN (select sec_accounts.id from accounts sec_accounts
  WHERE (sec_accounts.account_type_id = 344 AND ((`sec_accounts`.`segment_1` = 'MS')))
) as alloc_accounts ON alloc_accounts.id = order_line_allocations.account_id 
WHERE (`orders`.line_count = 0 OR
       `orders`.account_type_id IS NULL OR
       `orders`.account_type_id IN (NULL) OR 
       (non_alloc_accounts.id is not null) OR
       (alloc_accounts.id is not null)
) ORDER BY `orders`.`id` ASC LIMIT 90 \G;
```

This query is taking 7 seconds to complete which is too long

However, for other user:

```
SELECT `orders`.`id` FROM `orders` 
LEFT JOIN `order_lines` ON `order_lines`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN order_line_allocations ON order_line_allocations.order_line_id = order_lines.id
LEFT JOIN (select sec_accounts.id from accounts sec_accounts
  WHERE (sec_accounts.account_type_id = 8 AND ((`sec_accounts`.`segment_1` = '2D')))
) as non_alloc_accounts ON non_alloc_accounts.id = order_lines.account_id AND order_lines.allocation_count = 0
LEFT JOIN (select sec_accounts.id from accounts sec_accounts
  WHERE (sec_accounts.account_type_id = 8 AND ((`sec_accounts`.`segment_1` = '2D')))
) as alloc_accounts ON alloc_accounts.id = order_line_allocations.account_id 
WHERE (`orders`.line_count = 0 OR
       `orders`.account_type_id IS NULL OR
       `orders`.account_type_id IN (NULL) OR 
       (non_alloc_accounts.id is not null) OR
       (alloc_accounts.id is not null)
) ORDER BY `orders`.`id` ASC LIMIT 90 \G;
```

^ This just takes 0.03 sec. Notice the different is just in where clause of LEFT JOINS.  Specifically "=8" vs "=344" in 2 places.

**No. of accounts matching 8 and '2D' is 175667, for 344 and 'MS' its just 5648**.

I have the required indexes on all the tables

Table indexes:

**orders**

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `index_orders_on_po_number` (`po_number`),
KEY `index_orders_on_account_type_id` (`account_type_id`),
KEY `index_orders_on_created_by` (`created_by_id`),
KEY `index_orders_on_last_exported_at` (`last_exported_at`),
KEY `index_orders_on_status` (`status`),
KEY `index_orders_on_updated_at` (`updated_at`),
KEY `index_orders_on_updated_by` (`updated_by_id`),
KEY `index_orders_on_created_at_and_status` (`created_at`,`status`),
KEY `index_status_supplier_id` (`status`,`supplier_id`),
KEY `index_orders_on_line_count` (`line_count`)
```

**order_lines**

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `index_order_lines_on_bulk_price_id` (`bulk_price_id`),
KEY `index_order_lines_on_account_type_id` (`account_type_id`),
KEY `index_order_lines_on_created_at` (`created_at`),
KEY `index_order_lines_on_created_by` (`created_by_id`),
KEY `index_order_lines_on_order_id` (`order_id`),
KEY `index_order_lines_on_status` (`status`),
KEY `index_order_lines_on_updated_at` (`updated_at`),
KEY `index_order_lines_on_updated_by` (`updated_by_id`),
KEY `index_order_lines_on_order_id_and_position` (`order_id`,`position`),
KEY `index_order_lines_on_order_id_and_line_num` (`order_id`,`line_num`),
KEY `index_ol_on_header_id_reporting_total_savings_pct_created_at` (`order_id`,`reporting_total`,`savings_pct`,`created_at`),
KEY `index_ol_on_order_id_supplier_id_reporting_total` (`order_id`,`supplier_id`,`reporting_total`),
KEY `index_ol_on_order_id_commodity_id_reporting_total_ela_id` (`order_id`,`commodity_id`,`reporting_total`,`extra_line_attribute_id`),
KEY `index_order_lines_on_allocation_count_and_account_id` (`allocation_count`,`account_id`),
KEY `index_order_lines_on_account_id` (`account_id`),
KEY `index_order_lines_on_allocation_count` (`allocation_count`),
KEY `index_ol_on_acc_id_alloc_count_order_id` (`account_id`,`allocation_count`,`order_id`),
KEY `index_ol_on_order_id_account_id_alloc_count` (`order_id`,`account_id`,`allocation_count`)
```

**order_line_allocations**

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `index_order_line_allocations_on_account_id` (`account_id`),
KEY `index_order_line_allocations_on_account_type_id` (`account_type_id`),
KEY `index_order_line_allocations_on_order_id` (`order_id`),
KEY `index_order_line_allocations_on_order_line_id` (`order_line_id`)
```

**accounts**

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_account_type_id_and_active` (`account_type_id`,`active`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_1` (`segment_1`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_10` (`segment_10`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_11` (`segment_11`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_12` (`segment_12`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_13` (`segment_13`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_14` (`segment_14`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_15` (`segment_15`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_16` (`segment_16`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_17` (`segment_17`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_18` (`segment_18`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_19` (`segment_19`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_2` (`segment_2`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_20` (`segment_20`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_3` (`segment_3`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_4` (`segment_4`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_5` (`segment_5`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_6` (`segment_6`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_7` (`segment_7`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_8` (`segment_8`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_segment_9` (`segment_9`),
KEY `index_accounts_on_account_type_id` (`account_type_id`)
```

**EXPLAIN PLAN for slow query**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: orders
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: index_orders_on_account_type_id,index_orders_on_line_count
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: order_lines
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: index_order_lines_on_order_id,index_order_lines_on_order_id_and_position,index_order_lines_on_order_id_and_line_num,index_ol_on_header_id_reporting_total_savings_pct_created_at,index_ol_on_order_id_supplier_id_reporting_total,index_ol_on_order_id_commodity_id_reporting_total_ela_id,index_ol_on_order_id_account_id_alloc_count
          key: index_ol_on_order_id_commodity_id_reporting_total_ela_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: perf_amazon_qas1481_utf8mb4.orders.id
         rows: 2
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: order_line_allocations
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: index_order_line_allocations_on_order_line_id
          key: index_order_line_allocations_on_order_line_id
      key_len: 5
          ref: perf_amazon_qas1481_utf8mb4.order_lines.id
         rows: 3
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: sec_accounts
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_accounts_on_account_type_id_and_active,index_accounts_on_segment_1,index_accounts_on_account_type_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: perf_amazon_qas1481_utf8mb4.order_lines.account_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: sec_accounts
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_accounts_on_account_type_id_and_active,index_accounts_on_segment_1,index_accounts_on_account_type_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: perf_amazon_qas1481_utf8mb4.order_line_allocations.account_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
```

**EXPLAIN PLAN for fast query:**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: orders
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: index_orders_on_account_type_id,index_orders_on_line_count
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: order_lines
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: index_order_lines_on_order_id,index_order_lines_on_order_id_and_position,index_order_lines_on_order_id_and_line_num,index_ol_on_header_id_reporting_total_savings_pct_created_at,index_ol_on_order_id_supplier_id_reporting_total,index_ol_on_order_id_commodity_id_reporting_total_ela_id,index_ol_on_order_id_account_id_alloc_count
          key: index_ol_on_order_id_commodity_id_reporting_total_ela_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: perf_amazon_qas1481_utf8mb4.orders.id
         rows: 2
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: order_line_allocations
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: index_order_line_allocations_on_order_line_id
          key: index_order_line_allocations_on_order_line_id
      key_len: 5
          ref: perf_amazon_qas1481_utf8mb4.order_lines.id
         rows: 3
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: sec_accounts
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_accounts_on_account_type_id_and_active,index_accounts_on_segment_1,index_accounts_on_account_type_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: perf_amazon_qas1481_utf8mb4.order_lines.account_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: sec_accounts
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_accounts_on_account_type_id_and_active,index_accounts_on_segment_1,index_accounts_on_account_type_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: perf_amazon_qas1481_utf8mb4.order_line_allocations.account_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
```

How to speed up the query?

Comment: The predicate `orders.account_type_id IN (NULL)` always evaluates to false.

Comment: please edit your question to add (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename;` for all 4 tables and `explain SELECT ...` for both queries

Comment: How many are =8 versus =344?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: @Akshay-Goyal  Please consider posting TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE (each table); so we can see your current table and index structures.  Could you update the current runtimes with existing indexes.  We do not know if you are making progress or not, today. Thanks for the EXPLAIN results.  You did not mention there are differences in the segment_1 selection which means we need more EXPLAIN's posted.

Comment: Added table definitions and explain plans

Comment: @Akshay-Goyal Please consider posting TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE (each table); so we can see your current table and index structures. What you have posted is NOT the SHOW CREATE TABLE for each of the tables involved. We do NOT have any clues on how long your EXPLAIN took to complete the recent queries.

Answer (score 0):

These composite indexes may help:

```
order_lines:  INDEX(order_id, account_id, allocation_count)
order_line_allocations:  INDEX(order_line_id,  account_id)
accounts:  INDEX(account_type_id, segment_1)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both `INDEX(a)` and `INDEX(a,b)`, toss the former.

Can the two `LEFT JOINs` into `accounts` be combined?

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  And `EXPLAIN` for both 8 and 344.

`OR` makes it impractical to use an `INDEX` for optimization.